# validating message header in wcf

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I want to validate the values in the soap custom header to see if they are valid or not. I will be validating it against an external service.
I want to be able to send back the soap fault if the validation fails. 
Anyone has any suggestions on how to do this?
I tried by implementing the IOperationInvoker but when I throw an exception in preinvoke no response comes back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Message Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example - on the service you use AfterReceiveRequest:

```
object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
     // Retrieve Inbound Object from Request
     var header = request.Headers.GetHeader("XXXXX", "X");

     // evaluate header and throw FaultException if necessary

     return null;
}
```